# Python Pandas GroupBy returns blank rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataframe that has

```
date
month_year
business_id
sales
cost
```

by:

```
df.groupby(['month_year', 'business_id'])[['sales','cost']].sum()
```

Which returns:

```
month_year  business_id  sales  cost
2016/01     1             44     43 
            2             55     43
            3             55     34
```

But I need to insert this df into an sql table and need the format to be in a flat table with the month_year in every row:

```
month_year  business_id  sales  cost
2016/01     1             44     43 
2016/01     2             55     43
2016/01     3             55     34
```

How would I achieve this? (Note there are different months in the real data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add .reset_index() to the end of your groupby:

```
df.groupby(['month_year', 'business_id'])[['sales','cost']].sum().reset_index()
```